# Logically speaking, why can variables be substituted?

Tags: logic

Suppose that
$$a^2+a+1=b$$
Suppose also that $a=5/4$. What makes it valid to substitute $5/4$ into the first equation? Is it because equality is transitive?

Comment: It's by definition of equality and because in deductive systems there is a **postulated** rule that allows you to make such a substituion.

Comment: @GitGud, what do you mean by postulated rule?

Comment: I mean it's something that is true axiomatically. It's like that because you define it like that. Why is it that $1=1$ is true? It's by definition of equality, we define it that way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's just a basic principle of first-order logic with equality that if $a = b$ and $P(b)$ for a formula $P$, then $P(a)$. It's probably the most important aspect of equality that usually "goes without saying" in mathematics, except in logic courses.

Comment: Does this principle have a name?

Comment: @user101939 If you want to know the name to read about about it, you should look for *first order logic with equality*, *predicate calculus with equality*. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) link.

Comment: @user101939 It is called [Leibniz law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_of_indiscernibles)

Comment: Yeah, I just call it the substitution property.

Answer (score 9):

The reason why you can make such a substitution is that $a$ and $\dfrac{5}{4}$ are precisely the same, just written differently. Here's a long-winded way of making the substitution you describe.

\begin{align*}
a &= \frac{5}{4} & \\
a^2 &= \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2 &\text{squaring both sides}\\
a^2 + a &= \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{5}{4} &\text{adding the first two lines}\\
a^2 + a + 1 &= \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{5}{4}+1 &\text{adding $1$ to both sides}\\
b &= \left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{5}{4}+1 &\text{using the fact that $a$ satisfies the given equation}
\end{align*}

The right hand side is precisely what you obtain when you replace $a$ by $\dfrac{5}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two ways to understand equality.

One way to treat it is as a primitive logical identity sign: $a=b$ means that ‘$a$’ and ‘$b$’ are signs for the same thing.  Since they represent one and the same object, any property that can be proved of the object represented by $a$ must also hold of the object represented by $b$, because they are *the same object*. In this case one automatically gets a general substitution principle: $a$ can be replaced by $b$ because they mean the same thing: they are names for the same object.

Another way to proceed is the way that ZF set theory does, and to take equality as a defined property.  For example, ZF says that ‘$a=b$’ is an abbreviation for $$\forall x(x\in a\iff x\in b).$$

Two sets are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements.  If one does this, substitution must be asserted axiomatically, or proved as a theorem.  Without such a proof (trivial if substitution is an axiom) it might or might not hold. Transitivity is similar.

But the usual understanding in algebra is the first type: when we write something like ‘$x = \frac54$’ we mean that the name ‘$x$’ is a synonym for whatever object is denoted by $\frac54$.

Comment: This isn’t quite accurate.  Whether a logical system takes equality as a primitive relation or a defined one, one almost always gives the substitutivity property as an axiom or rule of the system.  In principle one certainly could have a system where substitutivity was a theorem, but that’s not what’s done in most presentations of ZF(C), or any other standard theory I know.